# Prime-NG File Uploader cancelling an image from upload queue and removing it from the array

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a prime ng file uploader in my angular application for uploading images.

This is it  : [image]

The way it works is that when you choose a file it will be added to an array which is later sent as a body in a post request to be handled in my asp.net core backend.

My problem is that when I click on the blue cancel button beside each image it removes it from the UI but the file is not removed from the array , so it will be saved too.
Is there a way I can bind to an event of this button to also remove the file from the array ?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind to the OnRemove event of primeng.